# how to display multiple contents in dropdown list in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown

I want to display multiple contents of country code in dropdown list in asp.net like this

[image]

Can I do it with bounding the data in dropdown list. I only display country codes with bounding data. Here is the code

```
public static class Countries
{
    public static ISO3166Country[] getCollection()
    {
        return new ISO3166Country[] {
            new ISO3166Country("Afghanistan", "+93"),
            ...
            new ISO3166Country("Zimbabwe", "+263" )
         };
    }

    public static List<string> getCountryList()
    {
        ISO3166Country[] array = getCollection();
        List<string> countries = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            countries.Add(array[i].countryName);
        }

        return countries;
    }

    public static List<string> getCountryCodeList()
    {
        ISO3166Country[] array = getCollection();
        List<string> countryCodes = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            countryCodes.Add(array[i].countryCode);
        }

        return countryCodes;
    }

}

public class ISO3166Country
{
    public ISO3166Country(string countryName, string dialCodes)
    {
        this.countryName = countryName;
        countryCode = dialCodes;
    }

    public string countryName { get; private set; }

    public string countryCode { get; private set; }
}
```

And bound data in page load

```
ddlPhoneCode.DataSource = Countries.getCollection();
ddlPhoneCode.DataBind();
```

I am also using bootstrap can I do this with bootstrap? any build in solution or have you already done this please give me the code.

Comment: You don't have to post 300 times the same line to show how you load the data, please read how to create a [mcve] before asking the next question.

Comment: This may solve your problem http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/33b051/binding-image-indropdownlist-in-asp-dotnet/